# Why does my function get called when it's not supposed to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 java script functions. If the first one returns true, the 2nd one is not to be executed. If the first one returns false, only then the second function to be executed.
So I am trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   

     function needsForcedReset() {

           if($("#showMessage").text().length > 0) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
     }

     function sendAlert() {
         //Sends an alert;
         alert('oh oh');
     }

     $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('in doc ready');
      if (needsForcedReset()) {
        alert('Need force reset, no check for alerts');
        return;
      }
      else {
        sendAlert();
     }

  });



  </script>
```

What I am seeing though, is that the sendAlert is being called regardless of what the needsForcedReset function return. How do I make it work?

**Edit: the showMessage is a div element**

Comment: what is showMessage?  A Textbox, a div?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your script....are you sure threre are no spaces or stuff in #showMessage

Answer (score 6):

Use the val() method if it's a input text box.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with your code. If the `needsForcedReset` returns `false` the `sendAlert` function will never get executed. And [here's the proof](http://jsfiddle.net/LmgdM/). So I guess that `needsForcedReset` always returns `true` which wouldn't be surprising if the element with `id="showMessage"` has some text, or if this is an input box you need to use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You left out the pertainent code that is causing his problem.  *Your* code runs, but his wont if that showMessage element is an INPUT.